# Boto3: describe security group rules by ip-permission.cidr filter

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto3

I was trying to list all SG which have 0.0.0.0/0 allowed in inbound rules and was testing with following line of code

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_security_group_rules(
Filters=[
dict(Name='ip-permission.cidr',Values= ['0.0.0.0/0'])
]
)
```

which gives me following error:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeSecurityGroupRules operation: The filter 'ip-permission.cidr' is invalid
```

Not sure what is the correct filter name as this is what i found on boto3 documentation

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_security_groups.html

here i see filter which has ip permission cidr in it

Comment: that's it perfect i was doing it wrong , thanks for pointing that

Answer (score 1):

The following code lists all the Security groups that has inbound rule 0.0.0.0/0  allowed.

```
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Initialize the AWS session
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id='-----',
        aws_secret_access_key='------',
        region_name='------'
    )
    
    # Create an EC2 client
    ec2_client = session.client('ec2')
    
    # Describe all security groups
    security_groups = ec2_client.describe_security_groups()
    
    # Create a list to store security group IDs that allow all traffic
    allowed_all_traffic_sgs = []
    
    # Iterate through security groups
    for sg in security_groups['SecurityGroups']:
        # Check inbound rules for each security group
        for rule in sg['IpPermissions']:
            # Check if there's an inbound rule allowing all traffic
            for ip_range in rule['IpRanges']:
                if ip_range['CidrIp'] == '0.0.0.0/0':
                    allowed_all_traffic_sgs.append(sg['GroupId'])
                    break  # No need to check further rules for this security group
    
    # Print the list of security group IDs that allow all traffic
    print("Security Groups allowing all traffic:")
    print(allowed_all_traffic_sgs)
```

Output -

```
Security Groups allowing all traffic:
['sg-sdfghj', 'sg-dfghjk', 'sg-sdfghjkm']
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re tryin' to use somethin’ that don't exist in the describe_security_group_rules. Instead, use describe_security_groups.

I tried it with AWS Lamvbda with python 3.11 and it works with the following code.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    response = client.describe_security_groups()

    # Use list comprehensions to get SGs with open world
    sgs_with_open_world = [
        sg['GroupId'] 
        for sg in response['SecurityGroups'] 
        if any(ip_range['CidrIp'] == '0.0.0.0/0' for permission in sg['IpPermissions'] for ip_range in permission['IpRanges'])
    ]

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': {
            'SecurityGroups': sgs_with_open_world
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": {
    "SecurityGroups": [
      "sg-asasasjasjaljsajs"
    ]
  }
}
```